# How can i select only the first element with Angular? "Django Backend"

Tags: python, django, angular, typescript

so as i mentioned in the title i have django working in the back-end sending my data to angular and i have a list of comments i want to show only the first element of my list in the html page i got this error while trying limitTo

```
Failed to compile.

src/app/app.component.html:8:3 - error TS2551: Property 'comment' does not exist on type ' 
AppComponent'. Did you mean 'comments'?

8 {{comment.author}}
~~~~~~~

src/app/app.component.ts:6:16
6   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

Here is my app.component.html :

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let topic of topics">
<h2> Hey  {{topic.author}}</h2>
</li>
<h2 ng-repeat="comment in comments | limitTo : 1">
{{comment.author}}
</h2>
</ul>
```

btw the *ngFor work perfectly i just need to take only the first element for the comments thank you

Comment: why wouldnt you just use `comments[0]` ?

Comment: @JoranBeasley that was the first thing i tried but i got this error : error TS2339: Property 'author' does not exist on type '{}'.
in my html : {{comments[0].author}}

Answer (score 0):

try this in your html template `{{comments[0]?.author}}`

Answer (score 0):

**This was the Solution :**

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let topic of topics">
<h2> Hey  {{topic.author}}</h2>
 </li>

{{comments[0]["author"]}}
</h2>
</ul>
```